# Using .filter in Django to see if title contains a certain string?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

My code is:

```
posts = Listing.objects.filter(title=q, is_live=1)
```

I need the equivalent of:

```
posts = Listing.objects.filter(q in title, is_live=1)
```

How can I just determine if a certain bit of text exists and isn't exactly equal to the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
posts = Listing.objects.filter(title__contains=q, is_live=1)
```